# type 'null' is not subtype of type "widget"

Tags: flutter, dart

someone help me plz. i can solve it .please solve this error  .why show null is not subtype please solve this error [image]

its textfiled code now plz solve this code.here we using textfiled code this called should called bulder

```
setDataTextField(data) {
    Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.blue),
          controller: _nameController =
              TextEditingController(text: data['name']),
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.blue),
          controller: _phoneController =
              TextEditingController(text: data['contract']),
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.blue),
          controller: _dobController = TextEditingController(text: data['dob']),
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.blue),
          controller: _genderController =
              TextEditingController(text: data['gender']),
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.blue),
          controller: _ageController = TextEditingController(text: data['age']),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 40.h,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 56.h,
          width: 1.sw,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              'UPDATE YOUR PROFILE',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.sp),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

its stream builder code

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users-data-form')
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              var data = snapshot.data;
              return setDataTextField(data);
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Share `setDataTextField` code.

Comment: done now solve this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setDataTextField` should have `return`.
change it to this.

```
Widget SetDataTextField(dynamic data) {
    return Column(
      children: [...]);
```

and inside `StreamBuilder` you should wrap your code inside this condition:

> if (snapshot.hasData) {YourCode}

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users-data-form')
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                var data = snapshot.data;
                return setDataTextField(data);
              }
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe u forgot the `return` left of `column` in the first line of your method?